# What is wrong with my code (it doesn't call the function)?

Tags: c

What is wrong with my code? It it doesn't call the function (I am an absolute beginner, just started 3 days ago).

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void whyy();

int main(){
    void whyy();
}

void whyy(){
    printf("lllllllllllll");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include the description of your problem and an actual question inside the body instead of the title (which should be a short summary of your problem).

Comment: As a hint: You have two statements like `void whyy();`. What do you think those statements are doing? What does your text-book, tutorials or teacher say about how to call a function?

Answer (score 4):

The `void whyy();` line inside `main` is *declaring* a function, not *calling* one. To call the function, just name it (with its required `()`):

```c
int main(){
    whyy();
    return 0;
}
```